# Staying restful but simplifying the new and create actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning ruby on rails. The project which I have in mind involves a welcome page that will take users to a room by clicking "new room"; something like welcompage.com/random_room_id. My approach right now is to use the new and create actions to eventually bring the user to the room, but I would like to do this with a single action. How can I do this but still follow the RESTful conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding of RESTful conventions in Ruby, the #welcome action is your `new`, the endpoint of the form (when the user clicks) is the `create`, and when s/he is taken to the new room, that's #show of that room.

I'm not sure what goals you would be pursuing by lessening the number of actions? If you have different verbs (GET, POST) you probably want a different controller action per verb.

Comment: I don't want to break RESTful. I think new->create->show is on the right track. Can the default home/welcome page be considered a new action?

Comment: The default welcome page can be `new`, yes. `new` is a GET request that does not modify data (as opposed to a `PUT` or `POST`), so there is no problem having `welcome` as `new`. I should also add that you really can take liberty with all these conventions, an angel will not come down from heaven and tell you that you are wrong. Further, having test coverage should give you courage to experiment or make changes ; )